# python mysql update failing when the string is huge

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table where a text column needs be updated. The column report_2_comments is the text column. When I update the column with a small string - "This is test message", I dont have any issues but when I update using the given below message, I get this error.

```
e ==  not enough arguments for format string

context = DbContext()
try:
    qry = """Update Report_Table 
                        set {2} = '{3}'
                        where valid_flag = 'Y' and report_status = 'C' 
                        and report_name = '{0}'
                        and date(report_run_date) = '{1}';
                    """.format('Daily Errors Report'
                        , '2016-07-09', 'report_2_comments', 
                        '8-3-2016 01:00 EST Affected DC region  1,000 errors over 2.5 hours (2%) 8-3-2016 13:00 EST Affected Virginia   500 errors over 11 hours (2%) 1233 8-3-2016 13:00 EST Affected 212/1412121001 - Date/skljld (sdlkjd)NOT_FOUND) 90,800 errors over 11 hours (2%) sldkdsdsd Fiber cut 8-3-2016 17:00 EST Affected 16703 - sdsdsd, WV (Tune Error) 15,400 errors over 7.5 hours (0.6%) sdkjd dskdjhsd sdkjhd')
    print 'update qry == ', qry
    output = context.execute(qry,())
except Exception as e:
    print 'e == ', e
```

qry

```
Update vbo.Report_Table 
                        set report_2_comments = '8-3-2016 01:00 EST Affected DC region  1,000 errors over 2.5 hours (2%) 8-3-2016 13:00 EST Affected Virginia   500 errors over 11 hours (2%) 1233 8-3-2016 13:00 EST Affected 212/1412121001 - Date/skljld (sdlkjd)NOT_FOUND) 90,800 errors over 11 hours (2%) sldkdsdsd Fiber cut 8-3-2016 17:00 EST Affected 16703 - sdsdsd, WV (Tune Error) 15,400 errors over 7.5 hours (0.6%) sdkjd dskdjhsd sdkjhd'
                        where valid_flag = 'Y' and report_status = 'C' 
                        and report_name = 'Daily Errors Report'
                        and date(report_run_date) = '2016-07-09';
```

Table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE Report_Table (
    id bigint(19) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    report_name varchar(200),
    report_run_date datetime,
    report_status char(25),
    valid_flag char(1),
    report_1_comments text(65535),
    report_2_comments text(65535),
    report_3_comments text(65535),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: what's the datatype of this column `report_2_comments`? post your table definition

Comment: Your SQL library (which?) thinks it is supposed to format the query string but is not provided the arguments. You could also try to get more information out of the Exception object as to where it originates. `Exception` is very unspecific.. Maybe it's because of the `%`? What's with the empty tuple in `execute()`?